# Spring Cache get key from the Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I have used spring cache in a spring boot application to store value against a certain key. I now have the value, is it possible to get the key from cache against the value? If so Please help.

I tried using solutions regarding `net.sf.ehcache.Cache` but for some reason it doesn't show any import suggestions and gives error **net.sf.ehcache.Cache cannot be resolved to a type**. I am new to spring cache so have no clue what to do further.

The dependencies in my project are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The code I am using is

```
public String getEmailByOtp(String otp)
{
    String email = "";
    Ehcache cache = (Ehcache) CacheManager.getCache("otpCache").getNativeCache();
    for (Object key: cache.getKeys()) {
        Element element = cache.get(key);
        if (element != null) {
            Object value = element.getObjectValue();     // here is the value
            if(value.equals(otp)) {
                email = key.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    return email;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Spring Cache](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and [EhCache](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/net.sf.ehcache.Cache) are two completely different implementations of caching mechanisms. Although there is a way to cast Spring-based cache to EhCache-based one, it doesn't mean Spring provides automatically its implementation. You have to import the EhCache library (using Maven, Gradle, etc.).

Here you go. You get an instance of`net.sf.ehcache.EhCache` which contains all the cache regions from Spring [`org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html).

```
EhCache cache = (EhCache) CacheManager.getCache("myCache").getNativeCache();
```

Then, it's not possible to access all the values directly like with the `Map`. Iterate through the keys and get the particular elements matching the key. This way you iterate through all the values as well.

```
for (Object key: cache.getKeys()) {
    Element element = cache.get(key);
    if (element != null) {
        Object value = element.getObjectValue();     // here is the value
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the snippets, however, I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I tried and getting the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getCache(String) from the type CacheManager` for now i autowired Cachemanager to have its object ... is this a correct approach?

Comment: and the next error is in the for loop its showing to me `The method getKeys() is undefined for the type CacheProperties.EhCache`

Comment: I haven't tested my code and I should include this information. Firstly, you can't mix the static and autowired content. Secondly, check if the library is properly imported. EhCache has this method: https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html#getKeys()

Comment: I beleive the import is correct ... the part where i cache the value is working fine since the past week i hope i didnt make a mistake in the import, `import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties.EhCache;
` this is the import i have in my code

Comment: You need `net.sf.ehcache.EhCache`.

Comment: net.sf.ehcache.EhCache this is not suggest to me by the IDE even though this is the solution i got from every where else. I have added the dependencies in my question can you let me know if they are correct

Comment: Update the project, force to reimport all the dependencies. What dependency have you included to the `pom.xml`?

Comment: You use `org.ehcache` but need `net.sf.ehcache.EhCache`. Try this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.5

Comment: it seems that my repo was not correct i tried maven install and got an issue of weblogic plugin... resolving them and after that will get back to you thanks for the help

Comment: `CacheManager.getCache("myCache")` at this piece of code i am getting error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getCache(String) from the type CacheManager `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176236/discussion-between-anas-and-nikolas).

Comment: CacheManager.getCache will not work because getCache is not static method.
also after autowiring Cachemanager when using the same code i get exception of casting
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache